# Unable to click selenium chromedriver

Tags: vb.net, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm unable to perform click by `cssselector` or even `xpath` or even send keys space or enter.

I think youtube is blocking it. Any help appreciate.

**My Code:**

```
Public Function OpenVideo(video As String)
    Try
        Form1.UpdateStatus("Opening video ...")
        If (Driver Is Nothing) Then
            Return ""
        End If
        _Status = True
        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(video)
        'Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
        'TESTING

        ' Driver.SwitchTo.Frame(0)
        Dim element = Driver.FindElementByCssSelector("#movie_player > div.ytp-chrome-bottom > div.ytp-chrome-controls > div.ytp-left-controls > span:nth-child(2) > button[aria-label='Play (k)'")
        element.click()


        ViewsByVideo = 0
        d = DateTime.Now
        If (clockTimer Is Nothing) Then
            Dim autoEvent As New AutoResetEvent(False)
            clockTimer = New Timer(AddressOf ClockFunction, autoEvent, 0, 1000)
        Else
            clockTimer.Change(0, 1000)
        End If
        IsPlaying = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        LogManager.AddLog(ex.Message)
    End Try
    _Status = False
End Function
```

**If possible** I would like to instead of clicking elements or button, just "HIT SPACE" and this way I can be sure it always press play as space is the same like play.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[google blocks automated traffic](https://support.google.com/websearch/thread/2596872?hl=en)

try using `cssSelector` at final step.
if that didn't work then might be there is DOM issue with page or automated script is blocked.